# RestKit 2.0 getObjectsAtPathForRelationship : Error perform pattern matching

Tags: json, cocoa, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am a little stuck with RestKit 2.0. 
I have a User-Entity on CoreData that has a relationship to an ActionStream-Entity which 
again has relations ships to Action-Entities.

User has relationship one_to_one ActionsStream
ActionsStream has relationship one_to_many Actions

When I log a user in I get some data and a token giving me access to the ActionStream. 
So I need to map the Json Reponse to my ActionsStream entity.

```
// Example Json ActionsStream with 2 Action items
{
   "total_count":2,
   "number_of_pages":2,
   "current_page":1,
   "items":[
      {
         "id":58606,
         "description":"dd "

      },
      {
         "id":58602,
         "description":"dd "

      }
   ]
}
```

My Action & ActionStream mapping is straight forward but I will add it for reference:

```
NSDictionary *mappingDict = @{  @"id" : @"id",
                                @"description" : @"description" };


NSDictionary *mappingDict = @{  @"total_count" : @"totalCount",
                                @"number_of_pages" : @"numberOfPages",
                                @"current_page" : @"currentPage"};
```

And I am hoping to load the file as follows.

```
- (void)loadUserActionss:(User*)user{

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[
                                                 [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[ActivityStream entityMapping:objectManager.managedObjectStore]
                                                                                              method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                         pathPattern:nil
                                                                                             keyPath:nil
                                                                                         statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]
                                                 ]];

[objectManager getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"actionSream"
                                ofObject:user
                                parameters:nil
                                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

                                   NSLog(@"Success");

                                }failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                    NSLog(@"Failure");
                                }];
```

}

The error I get is as follows:
+[RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:]
**'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Pattern string must not be empty in order to perform pattern matching.'**

I am new to RestKit so any guidance would help, including if I am handling the situation in the correct way and should be using a different method.
Thank You.
Al

Comment: Have you setup any routes? How have you taught RestKit about the `activitySream` relationship and how to navigate it? Also, the mappings you show don't deal with `items`.

Comment: Routes: I didn't realize I needed to set up routes. Do I need to do that? And I hoped giving the argument getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:@"actionSream" would be enough for RestKit. As for Items, I was hoping to do the ActionStream first and then worry about the actions. At the moment I just get the error. Note "Activities" is "Actions", was just making a simple example for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you see is because you are using the `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship` method but you haven't given RestKit enough information to know how to request that information from the server. You can supply the information in one of 2 ways:

1. Set the path parameter when you call the method
2. Create an `RKRoute` which describes the route (path) for that relationship name

The error you see (`'Pattern string must not be empty in order to perform pattern matching.'`) describes this lack of information.

Comment: Solved with [RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName...] which I didn't know about. Thanks.